# Finding Minimum Distance of a Point from Curve

Tags: analysis, geometry

While finding the distance of a point from a curve (which is graph of a function), the usual method I saw is as follows: given a point and a curve $\{x,f(x)\}\colon c\in\mathbb{R}$ (where $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function), the distance of $(x,f(x))$ from $(a,b)$ is $D(x)=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(f(x)-b)^2}$. To obtain the shortest distance of $(a,b)$ from the curve, we solve $D'(x)=0$ for $x$ (and mostly we have onlyfinitely many solutions) and for these $x$, we compute distances of $(x,f(x))$ to $(a,b)$ and find the minimum.

I would like to see the theory behind the process "solving $D'(x)=0$, ...", since I couldn't notice why $D$ is differentiable?, and if it is differentiable, why $D'(x)$ should be taken zero to obtain closest point? Of course, there would be certain assumptions about differentiability of $f$, but I didn't find such Theory in most common calculus and analysis texts.

Please suggest the references in which these questions are tackled 'theoretically'.

Comment: If $(x_0, y_0)$ is closest ( or farthest) then the vector $(x_0-a, y_0-b)$  ( the position vector) is perpendicular to the tangent vector to the curve at point $(x_0, y_0)$. As for the method in general note that you might as well look at the extrema of the distance squared, a nicer function.

Comment: Try searching the conditions for max or min of a function using derivatives in Google

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental idea in problems of maximizing and minimizing is that at a peak of the graph of a function, or at the bottom of a trough, the tangent is horizontal. That is, the derivative $f′(x_i)$ is $0$ at points $x_i$ at which $f(x_i)$ is a maximum or a minimum. In finding the shortest distance, they usually assume the distance function to be monotonically increasing and instead of the square root distance, the squared function $D^2(x)$ is minimized.

This method obviously has its own limitations like differentiability and the problem of local minimum/maximum in non-linear functions. This is the most widespread method of finding solution to optimization problem e.g. [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).
These problems are mostly solved numerically and hence most optimization books are good references, like [Numerical Optimization, by Nocedal & Wright](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-40065-5).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific to the frame of a distance computation. You are in fact just trying to find the global minimum of some function.

Theory tells you that for a continuous function, this minimum occurs either at a stationary point, or at an endpoint of the domain. If the function has discontinuities, you also consider the values at these discontinuities.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't much of a theory, except that the infinitesimal shift in the dependent variable causes nearly zero change.

To minimize any function of multiple variables we write $df=0.$ However, a minimum value locally is when the tangent line/plane becomes flat, because there is no rate of change: they are literally the largest or smallest values of $f$ in their locality, (in other words they are minimized or maximized,) which can be visualized graphically as a hill or a valley point; in higher dimensions this extends to add saddle points and other numerous variations.

So when we want to minimize distance from a curve to a point, or a curve to another curve, we want to minimize the distance function. Lets say we want to minimize the distance between $p(t),q(t')$, in other words to find the values of $t,t'$ that represent the closest points to each other on either curve, or that the line segment of shortest distance between any one point and another on either curve: we take

$$d|p-q|=0,\\\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|p-q|=0,\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}|p-q|=0.$$

The second understanding is that if we have a function $f(x)$, that $f(x+dx)$ and $f(x-dx)$ are only infinitesimally larger or smaller. In other words, $f\approx f(x+dx)=f+f'dx,$ or $f'=0.$ I've illustrated this case here:

[image]

and similarly for the maximum case. More practically, that $f(x-dx)=f(x)=f(x+dx),$ which also implies $f'=0.$